# How to integrate google jquery library into a php page

Tags: php, jquery, integration

As the title requests, how do I integrate the google jquery library into a php page so I can utilize jquery scripting?

EDIT: I suppose "Utilize" is a better word than integrate for this question.

EDIT2: The html code is generated by php. Editing a small opensource app.

Comment: Just include both of mentioned libraries in `<head>` tag ? ;-)

Comment: @hsz if the html code is generated with php is this the same case?

Comment: Sure - if you want to use both of those libraries, just hook them on generated page.

Comment: In this context, PHP is a server-size language and generally has nothing to do with the client-size script running in the users' browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean how do you include the Google-hosted version of the jQuery library in your PHP page? You can just add a script tag to the HTML like so:

```
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Way cleaner if you do: `text/javascript` in stead of `test/javascript` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use jQuery 1.7 you cannot use Google's CDN because you will get a 404.

There are others though:

http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery

Just add this before the `</body>` closing tag:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You could also add it in the `<head>` section of your html, but if you do that the page will wait till the script is loaded before loading the rest of the page.

If you add it at the end of your HTML you make sure the script won't delay loading of the actual page elements.

Answer (score 1):

As a Javascript library, JQuery is read, interpreted, and run by the web browser.  So, no matter how you generate your HTML, just make sure you include a `<script>` tag referencing the library, and it will be loaded by the browser.